# Set product purchase note programmatically in WooCommerce via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to programmatically set the purchase note of all WooCommerce products based on the value of their `pdf_file` custom field. How can I do this in PHP?

Here's the code snippet that I'm working with:

```
/*******************************************************************************
Programmatically add custom purchase note to product
*******************************************************************************/
function add_purchase_note( ) {
    global $product;

    if ( get_field('pdf_file', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $note = 'Thank you for purchasing! Please <a target="_blank" href="';
        $note = $note . get_field('pdf_file', $product->get_id() ) . '">click here</a> to view your purchase.';

        $product->set_purchase_note($note);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'add_purchase_note',  1, 1  );
```

I'm getting a `Site is experiencing technical issues` on my `if` condition - so I'm not sure if I'm using the right WooCommerce action hook too (I also used `wp_enqueue_scripts` but that doesn't work), or if this is the right approach to do it.

Comment: Not sure but 2 things first, 1. `woocommerce_after_main_content` isn't a good hook to use if you want this to happen when the product is ordered. and 2. purchase notes are saved on the Order... so `set_purchase_note()` doesn't exist for `$product` object... which is probably your fatal error. Turn on `WP_DEBUG_LOG`.

Comment: Nope, I was wrong about that second part. It does exist, though I'm not sure what it does. WooCommerce core supports digital products... why the need for what I think is ACF?